# tuning of marimba in a jazz band

Tags: jazz, tuning, percussion

I started playing the marimba and although it seems a bit unusual I wish to be part of a jazz band with that instrument. Fortunately, before buying my own instrument I found out that marimbas have different pitches, some really nice ones are A=443. But I do need to get an instrument that is tuned at A=440 to fit in with a band, right?

Comment: This Q&A may shed some tight: [Why is A=442 the common tuning for percussion instruments?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/40605/why-is-a-442-the-common-tuning-for-percussion-instruments).

Answer (score 6):

Although lots of bands choose A=440Hz as their tuning base, it doesn't have to be.

Marimbas are not possible to tune up/down, so they are what they are. However - all other instruments (discounting pianos/organs/Fender Rhodes et al) *can* be adjusted. Decades ago, in bands, where there was a piano at the venue that was enough in tune to be playable, my band would tune to it - inevitably a bit low - so at least everyone was in tune. Even if there's an electronic keyboard to be part of the band, most have the facility to be fine-tuned.

So, whilst it would seem advisable to have a marimba in 'standard' tuning, if A=443Hz provides a far better instrument, I'd have thought all the other band members would be able to match that with no real problems, except perhaps for those with AP.

Comment: "If A=443 provides a far better instrument"  I don't see how tuning a bit sharp would change the quality of the instrument at all.

Comment: @Edward I suppose it was a reference to the OP saying "some really nice ones are A=443", even if it's not clear if that's an assumption based on availability, maker production or just misunderstanding.

Comment: @Edward - not tuned sharp, as such, but tuned to a different A pitch. Probably for a market in a different part of the world.

Comment: With "nice" I meant that I found an affordable instrument with bars made of palisander. The sound of those bars is supposed to be the best. As to the "different markets": It seems to be more a question of whether playing in a classical orchestra, where the standard tuning in many countries is A=442 (even 443) or playing Jazz, Pop etc. where the standard tuning in any country is A=440. On the other hand even Vibraphones - and they are pure Jazz, aren 't they? - come in 442 and 443.

Comment: Vibraphones appear in orchestras, and part of the vibraphone market (probably a large part) is high school marching bands, where they will be played alongside marimbas.

Answer (score 0):

Not all instruments are at the same pitch. I heard a piano tuner interviewed, who tuned pianos for the big concert halls, and he said for piano concertos he tuned the piano 1.5 cents sharp. Certain instruments are tuned slightly sharp, I think the accordion is for ensembles. Also 440 is not universal, in Vienna I believe it is 442-444.

If the marimba or vibraphone is flat in relation to the the ensemble it is not a good sound. An example was on British light music radio programmes. The style many years ago was to finish a piece on a rising violin scale, followed by a vibraphone chord. Because the violins would rise in pitch throughout the performance the final vibraphone added 6th chord was often flat.

I would suggest you go on a specialist tuned percussion forum, or talk to a marimba technician. My guess is the marimba is deliberately tuned slightly sharp.

Comment: 1.5 cents would hardly be noticeable -- A4 would be 440.38 Hz, so it would beat against 440 Hz slightly faster than every three seconds.

Comment: I'd love to hear an example of that flat marimba in a "British light music radio programme". Any chance of a link? Thank you.